# API REST structure

Tags: rest, api

I'm implementing an API REST, and I'm not sure about the structure.
I have a lot of tables at database, divided by elements. Let's call them `A, B, C, D, E`.

Every element has an ID, and `A` contains a list of `B` elements, `B` contains a list of `C` elements an so on.

I'm not sure if at "A" endpoint I should return something like

```
{
   id: 1,
   ...,
   listB: [1,2,3]
}
```

or something like

```
{
   id: 1,
   ...,
   listB: [
      {
          id:1,
          ...
      },
      {
          id:2,
          ...
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

I think that first way I will need to do a lot of request to have the full information of "A" element, but having full "A" element each time I request doesn't seems very good also.

Is there a another way? Which one is the best (or the standard) and why?

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on what the endpoint is used for.**

If, for example, endpoint "A" is consumed in such a way that only its immediate children are needed, then there is no need to traverse the entire data structure and return all grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc. as the extra data would be unnecessary.

However, if your client needs to get all information about "A", then a single request may be preferred.

An example that comes to mind is a nested datagrid, where you can expand each row for more detailed information. Do you want to front-load the data retrieval, or get data on the fly when a user expands each row? It depends on your application.